# what is the thread model of mysql and innodb?

Tags: innodb

I am learning the architecture of MySQL and InnoDB, and the thread model combined with the pluggable engine system confuses me. It is claimed that MySQL instance is one process with many threads, and InnoDB has many background threads such as master-thread, io threads to deal with callbacks of kernel aio. What's more, I find that the connection pool is managed by the MySQL layer not the pluggable InnoDB layer.

Then how do MySQL threads manage connections and their requests, and how does MySQL request go to kernel aio does it cooperate with InnoDB io thread?

Answer (score 1):

A connection is given its own process (or thread, depending on OS).  That process runs along as if it were a single process, except for access to a large number of caches, tables, etc.  To deal with them, there are many "mutexes".  These are used to give exclusive access to one process to, say, insert/delete something in the buffer_pool or table cache, etc.

In the old days, there were fewer Mutexes.  For example, to do anything with the buffer pool a single (or maybe a few) Mutex granted access.  This was fine when there was one CPU or maybe two.  But when servers had 8 cores, they realized that this was not fine-grained enough.  So there was an overhaul of the mutexes.  (IIRC, it was spearheadded by Percona.)

Because of these mutexes, 4 processes could work "simultaneously" before they stumbled over each other.  More that 8 cores --> throughput actually went down.  (And latency went through the roof.)

As new versions came out, that number increased.  With MySQL 8, it is possibly over 64.

Another thing that happened was "instances" of buffer_pools and table_open_caches.  This was a straightforward way to split a mutex into several.

I am less familiar with the I/O thread model.  I suspect the thread (for one connection) somehow signals another thread to do the work for it.

Also, several things are left to background tasks:  flushing to logs, updating index blocks from the "change buffer", read-ahead, flushing of "dirty" pages from the buffer_pool, cleaning up BTrees, etc.  Note that all of these would use the appropriate Mutex(es) so as not to step on each other and the various connection processes.

The "pluggable engine" system needs a different kind of chatter -- between the generic handler and the engine-specific code.  I suspect this is orthogonal to the mutexes, background threads, etc.

The "connection pool" would be yet-another array (or list) of something, and multiple processes would want to grab/release an item in that array.  Hence its own mutex(es).